# Solving PDE with power series

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, series-expansion, boundary-conditions

I would like to solve the PDE

$$\partial_{x}f(x,y) + f(x,y)^2 = g(x,y)$$

with $f(0,0)=0$ and $\partial_y f(0,0)=0$ using a power series ansatz, i.e. I have an explicit expression for $g(x,y)=\sin(x+y)\cos(x)\cos(2y)$ and want to find the first coefficients of a power series $f(x,y) = \sum_{n} c_n x^{n_1}y^{n_2}$ solving this equation. I wonder if there is a way in mathematica to do this to get the first let's say $\vert n\vert\le 11$ coefficients.

Comment: Use `Series` to expand the `D[f[x,y],x]+f[x,y]^2-V[x,y]`about `{0, 0}` and `Solve` for the coefficients.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I am very sorry, but since I am not very familiar with Mathematica, do you think you could provide a minimal working example?

Comment: @bbgodfrey In particular, how do I implement the initial conditions?

Comment: The expansion I suggested will contain f[0,0] and f[0,y]/.y->0.  Set them to zero.  First try the expansion with a small `n`.

Comment: It is late here.  If no one has provided an answer by tomorrow morning, I may do so.  In the meantime, search this web site for similar questions.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks. The issue is that Series outputs an enormous expression and manually finding f[0,0] and f[0,y]/.y by hand and removing the terms is already cumbersome (there must be a way around this). Then I also do not know how to solve for those coefficients.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: I dont understand the question. 

The ODE f' + f^2 = a + b x + c x^2  or anything else solvable by DSolve yields a solution of. Making the coefficients to be  functions of y  with a given derivative at y=0 can be done by substituons

Comment: This problem is ill posed.  To obtain a solution, derivatives of `f[0,y]` to all orders must be specified for `y =0`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I see, we can assume that they are all zero.

Comment: @RolandF this cannot be solved by DSolve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the additional initial conditions specified in a comment, the power series can be obtained by expanding the PDE as a series and solving the resulting algebraic equations.  For instance,

```
n = 3;  
CoefficientList[Normal@Series[
    D[f[x, y], x] + f[x, y]^2 - Sin[x + y] Cos[x] Cos[2 y], {x, 0, n}, {y, 0, n + 1}] 
    /. {f[0, 0] -> 0, Derivative[0, _][f][0, 0] -> 0}, {x, y}];
Union@Flatten[%];
Solve[Thread[% == 0], Union@Variables@%] // Flatten;
Sum[Derivative[m1, m2][f][0, 0] x^m1 y^m2/{m1! m2!}, {m1, 1, n + 1}, 
    {m2, 0, n + 1}] /. %

(* {x^2/2 - x^4/6 + x y - x^3 y/3 - x^4 y/4 - 5 x^2 y^2/4 - 
    x^3 y^2/3 + 5 x^4 y^2/12 - 13 x y^3/6 + 13 x^3 y^3/18 + 
    7 x^4 y^3/6 + 41 x^2 y^4/48 + 13 x^3 y^4/9 - 41 x^4 y^4/144} *)
```

The results rapidly becomes larger as `n` is increased.

Comment: Problem 1: This is good in principle, but not so good in practical terms of how far it gives a decent approximation. I'll show a different approach and you can compare the discrepancies as `(x,y)` increase. Problem 2: I meant to upvote anyway, but apparently hit the wrong arrow and now cannot change it. Please edit so I can replace the errant downvote.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I agree that a power series is not the optimal approach to solving this PDE, but perhaps the OP had a specific reason for requesting it.  Also, I have edited my answer, as you requested.

Comment: Yes, maybe there was a reason. Thanks for editing, vote problem solved. (They should all be so simple.)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than use a series expansion, you might treat this as a parametric ODE and use `ParametricNDSolve`. Here of course `y` is the parameter, as it does not appear in the derivatives. I just solve from `x=0` to `x=2`.

```
psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{D[f[x], x] + f[x]^2 == 
     Sin[x + y]*Cos[x]*Cos[2*y], f[0] == 0}, f[x], {x, 0, 2}, y];
```

Define an evaluation function.

```
pvalue[x0_, y0_] := psol[y0] /. x -> x0
```

I'll show this for a fairly modest range.

```
xmax = 1;
ymax = .7;
p1 = Plot3D[pvalue[x, y], {x, 0, xmax}, {y, 0., ymax}]
```

[image]

To compare to the series solution proposed by @bgodfrey we can do as follows.

```
pxy = x^2/2 - x^4/6 + x y - x^3 y/3 - x^4 y/4 - 5 x^2 y^2/4 - 
   x^3 y^2/3 + 5 x^4 y^2/12 - 13 x y^3/6 + 13 x^3 y^3/18 + 
   7 x^4 y^3/6 + 41 x^2 y^4/48 + 13 x^3 y^4/9 - 41 x^4 y^4/144;

p2 = Plot3D[pxy, {x, 0, xmax}, {y, 0., ymax}]
```

[image]

One can see these are close for a while but start to disagree, somewhat violently, in one corner (could use `Show[{p1,p2}]` to see it in more detail).

I should add that this method too will have its limitations-- the plot really does get wild beyond `y=1.2` or so. I do not know if it's intrinsic to the problem or rather a limitation in the capabilities of `ParametricNDSolve`. Some experimenting also suggests it has no issue with `y<0` until somewhere past `y=-4.5`.

Comment: Problem 3: I munged the adding of images. How do I fix this?

Comment: Images now visible.

Comment: @bgodfrey What was the magic word?

Comment: I pressed <Enter> immediately after "past `y=-4.5`.".

Answer (score 0):

```
V[x_, y_] := Sin[x + y] Cos[x] Cos[2 y]
f[x_, y_] := Sum[c[n1, n2] x^n1 y^n2, {n1, 0, 11}, {n2, 0, 11}]
L = D[#, x] + #^2 &;
eqn = L[f[x, y]] - V[x, y] == 0;
sol = Solve[{f[0, 0] == 0, D[f[x, y], y] /. y -> 0 == 0}, Flatten@Table[c[n1, n2], {n1, 0, 11}, {n2, 0, 11}]];
Table[c[n1, n2] /. sol[[1]], {n1, 0, 2}, {n2, 0, 2}]
Expand[eqn /. sol[[1]]] // Simplify
```

Comment: I reduced 11 to 1 and still this code just keeps on running. Is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: Your code contains errors. Also, may I suggest that, when you provide an answer, please include a sample result from running your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I have not made an error of reading the question, its a trival DSolve problem, not really a partial differential equation. We solve without that cos 2y term for a constant a. With cos y -term the equation is returned unsolved  -our known complexity problem with trigonometry trees in the forests.

```
sol[x_, y_] =  f[x] /. DSolve[f '[x] ==  a  Sin[x + y] Cos[x] - f[x]^2, f, 
 x] [[1]] /. {a -> Cos[2 y]};

sol1[x_,y_]=sol[x,y]/.Solve[sol[0,0]==0,C[1]][[1]];

D[sol1[x, y], x] + sol1[x, y]^2 // Simplify;

Out=Cos[x] Cos[2 y] Sin[x + y]
```